# App.config is not generating

Tags: c#, binding, app-config, endpoint-address

I have added a service reference (https://cawc-test.crm.ap2.oraclecloud.com/mklLeads/SalesLeadService?WSDL) in my .NET visual studio code. But its not generating `app.config` file. I have also tried using the svcutil.exe in visual studio command prompt. I have also tried unchecking the 'Resuse types in referenced assemblies' by clicking the Advanced button while adding the service reference. But still `App.config` file is not generating.

```
client = new SalesLeadServiceClient();
_client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = " ";
_client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = " ";

EndpointAddress endPointAddr = new EndpointAddress(address);
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
_client = new SalesLeadServiceClient(binding, endPointAddr);
BindingElementCollection elements = _client.Endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().IncludeTimestamp = false;
_client.Endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(elements);
igcomp.PrepareConnectSession(_client.ChannelFactory);
```

I have added the following code in my class. But still it is giving the 'could not find default endpoint element that references contract'.

It will be grateful if anyone can suggest any solution on this?